# Creating Python Package (setuptools) - No module named

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I'm trying to create a python package for the first time, using `setuptools`.

Let's imagine my package is named `qwerty`.
Here's my project structure:

```
qwerty (folder)
++ src (folder)
--++ __init__.py
--++ control.py
--++ modes.py
--++ data.dic
--++ utils.py
--++ version.py
--++ qwerty.py
++ __init__.py
++ __main__.py
CHANGELOG.md
commands.txt
README.md
image.gif
setup.py
```

My `setup.py` contains the following code:

```py
import setuptools as st
import os

exec(open(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "qwerty/src/version.py")).read())

st.setup(
    include_package_data=True,
    version=__version__,
    (...)
    package_data={"": ["*.dic"]},
    packages=st.find_packages(where="qwerty"),
    package_dir={"": "qwerty"},
    entry_points={"console_scripts": ["qwerty=qwerty.__main__:main"]}
)
```

And my `__main__.py` contains the following code:

```py
from .src.qwerty import main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm using the following command to create/install the package:

```bash
$ pip install .
```

When I install the program, it is installed in `/usr/local/bin`. My goal here is that the final binary executes the `main` function located in `qwerty/src/qwerty.py`. But I must be doing something wrong because after installing the package, when I run the program, I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/qwerty", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('qwerty==1.0.3', 'console_scripts', 'qwerty')())
  File "/usr/local/bin/qwerty", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 171, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qwerty'
```

I already tried using `entry_points={"console_scripts": ["qwerty=qwerty.src.qwerty:main"]}` as the entry point in `setup.py`, but got the exact same output.

Can someone try to explain me what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you executing the main?

Comment: @mad_ I'm just executing the program as: 
$ qwerty --help